# How do I click a button inside DIV tag via webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have this button:

```html
<div class="card-footer text-right">
  <input id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Log In" />
```

And have written the code to click it as:

```html
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'btn btn-sm btn-primary')]")).click();
```

which does not work. Any help ?

Comment: is the above input element inside an iframe?

Comment: No, it is not inside an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that whenever an element is present in the HTML DOM for better performance we should try to access those elements through their respective locators `id` or `name` first. Next we should try `linkText`,`tagName`,`css` and `xpath`

As per the element in your code, you can try these options:

`driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();`

OR

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login']")).click();`

OR

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-footer text-right']/input[@id='login']")).click();`

Now, as you are seeing `ElementNotVisibleException` we will introduce an ExplicitWait for the element to be visible then try to click on it as follows:

```
    WebElement myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-footer text-right']/input[@id='login']")));
    myElement.click();
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I am trying this in IE11, and for some reason it does not click on this element, even when i have implemented the code above.

Comment: Try the updated option. Let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: Atleast now it is "trying" to click on the element. 
I got this error when I used your updated code:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element

I checked the DOM properties also where the hidden property is false.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element

Comment: @SandeepSaikia you probably need to click the `div`, not the `input`. So basically this answer plus an `ancestor` axes.. `By.xpath("//input[@id='login']/ancestor::div")`. Or even better `//div[./input[@id='login']]`

Comment: @SandeepSaikia Great, we are petty closer now. Just try to add some Explicit Wait for the element to be visible & then try to click. That should work for you.

Comment: @SandeepSaikia added my code to introduce some ExplicitWait before clicking on the element. Update me the status.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the login button is not visible or clickable when your script runs. Try adding a WebDriver wait. For example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                 By.xpath("//div[@class='card-footer text-right']/input[@id='login']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='card-footer text-right']/input[@id='login']"))
      .click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems div here won't stand in the way,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login']")).click();
```

So, what this is doing is, it is looking for input tags all over the page and it doesn't matter what ancestors any of them may have. Then it selects the element which has 'login' as the value across the id attribute.

Comment: I am trying this in IE11, and for some reason it does not click on this element, even when i have implemented the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.card-footer.text-right input#login"));
WebDriverWait wait =  new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(yourElement));
yourElement .click();
```